# Laravel Sql software

Tags: sql, laravel

This query I wrote works in sql but it doesn't work in Laravel. Can you give me information on this subject? Sorry for the sloppy english

```
SELECT
    mydatas.dataID, 
    `data`.nickname, 
    users.`name`, 
    mydatas.workingID, 
    mydatas.updated_at, 
    `data`.hastaadi, 
    `data`.cep1, 
    `data`.cep2
FROM
    mydatas
    LEFT JOIN
    users
    ON 
        USERS.id = mydatas.workuserID
    INNER JOIN
    `data`
    ON 
        `data`.id = mydatas.dataID
WHERE
    `data`.nickname IN ('Deneme')
GROUP BY
    mydatas.dataID
```

**Sql Result Screen**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69P31.png)

**The Error I Got In Laravel**

```
{
    "message": "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'my2call.data.nickname' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: SELECT DISTINCT\n\tmydatas.dataID,\n\t`data`.nickname,\n\tusers.`name`,\n\tmydatas.workingID,\n\tmydatas.updated_at ,\n\t`data`.hastaadi,\n\t`data`.cep1,\n\t`data`.cep2\nFROM\n\tmydatas\n\tLEFT JOIN\n\tusers\n\tON\n\t\tUSERS.id = mydatas.workuserID\n\tINNER JOIN\n\t`data`\n\tON\n\t\t`data`.id = mydatas.dataID\n\nWHERE\n\t`data`.nickname in ('Deneme') and\n date(mydatas.updated_at) >= ('2020-12-07')\n\tAND date(mydatas.updated_at) < ('2021-01-05+1')\nGROUP BY (mydatas.dataID)\n\n)",
    "exception": "Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException",
    "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\My2Call\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php",
    "line": 671,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\My2Call\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php",
            "line": 631,
            "function": "runQueryCallback",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\My2Call\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php",
            "line": 339,
            "function": "run",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\My2Call\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\DatabaseManager.php",
            "line": 367,
            "function": "select",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection",
            "type": "->"
        },
        ....
```

Comment: it's not about laravel, it's the strict mode in your database (yeah there is a config in laravel for that in database.php) but you should not change it, you should adjust your query to work in strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

you should run sql like this

```
SELECT
    mydatas.dataID, 
    data.nickname, 
    users.name, 
    mydatas.workingID, 
    mydatas.updated_at, 
    data.hastaadi, 
    data.cep1, 
    data.cep2
FROM
    mydatas
    LEFT JOIN
    users
    ON 
        users.id = mydatas.workuserID
    INNER JOIN
    data
    ON 
        data.id = mydatas.dataID
WHERE
    data.nickname IN ('Deneme')
GROUP BY
    mydatas.dataID
```

Comment: It Didn't Work Again Given the same error.
GROUP BY
     mydatas.dataID
it works the moment i delete it